# Mule ESB: Can not de-reference JSON object array

Tags: json, mule, esb, jsonpath

I have a flow that returns the following JSON Object:

```
[{"1":444}]
```

The "1" represent the database row from a select sum() statement.

This is an unusual JSON object, and the unusual way to dereference the value of 444 in JSONPath is the following:

```
$.[0].1
```

This is the flow I use to print out the entire JSON Object:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns:db="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.5.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db/current/mule-db.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd">
    <db:generic-config name="Generic_Database_Configuration" url="jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/TEST:user=instuid;password=instpw;" driverClassName="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" doc:name="Generic Database Configuration"/>
    <flow name="test2Flow1" doc:name="test2Flow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <db:select config-ref="Generic_Database_Configuration" doc:name="Database" doc:description="test">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[SELECT SUM(BALANCE) FROM BENCHMARKING.ACCOUNT]]></db:parameterized-query>
        </db:select>
        <response>
            <set-payload value="#['---&gt;  , payload: ' + payload]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        </response>
        <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

So I use the following SetPayload Expression, and get the following result:

```
#['--->  , payload: ' + payload]


C:\curl>curl http://localhost:8081
--->  , payload: [{"1":444}]
C:\curl>
```

So now I want to simply extract the value 444.  So I am thinking I need to do something like the JSONPath statement of

```
$.[0].1
```

So I try the following SetPayload expression and get the following result:

```
#['--->  , payload: ' + payload.[0].1]


C:\curl>curl http://localhost:8081
[Error: unbalanced braces { ... }]
[Near : {... '--->  , payload: ' + payload.[0].1 ....}]
                                            ^
[Line: 1, Column: 32] (org.mule.api.expression.InvalidExpressionException). Mess
age payload is of type: String
```

OK, that makes sense, so I try again with the following:

```
#['--->  , payload: ' + payload.\1330\135.1]

C:\curl>curl http://localhost:8081
[Error: unexpected end of statement]
[Near : {... '--->  , payload: ' + payload.\1330\135.1 ....}]
                                   ^
[Line: 1, Column: 23] (org.mule.api.expression.InvalidExpressionException). Mess
age payload is of type: String
```

So how can I write this SetPayload expression, so that it will return the value of 444 given the JSON object of

```
[{"1":444}]
```

Thanks

**EDIT**

I changed my flow as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns:db="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.5.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db/current/mule-db.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd">
    <db:generic-config name="Generic_Database_Configuration" url="jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/TEST:user=instuid;password=instpw;" driverClassName="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" doc:name="Generic Database Configuration"/>
    <flow name="test2Flow1" doc:name="test2Flow1">
            <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP" path="mule/getBalance"/>
        <db:select config-ref="Generic_Database_Configuration" doc:name="FB Database" doc:description="test">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[SELECT SUM(BALANCE) FROM BENCHMARKING.ACCOUNT]]></db:parameterized-query>
        </db:select>
        <set-payload value="#[message.payload[0]['1']]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <json:json-to-object-transformer doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

However, I get the following output:

```
C:\curl>curl http://localhost:8081/mule/getBalance
¼φ ♣sr ↔org.mule.module.json.JsonDataZ╫♦♠╓▀☺┤☻ ☺L ♦nodet ▼Lorg/codehaus/jackson/
JsonNode;xp{sr  java.io.NotSerializableException(Vx τå▬5☻  xr ↔java.io.ObjectStr
eamExceptiond├Σkì9√▀☻  xr ‼java.io.IOExceptionlÇsde%≡½☻  xr ‼java.lang.Exception
detailMessaget ↕Ljava/lang/String;[ 5'9w╕╦♥ ♥L ♣causet §Ljava/lang/Throwable;L
stackTracet ▲[Ljava/lang/StackTraceElement;xpq t !org.codehaus.jackson.node.IntN
odeur ▲[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;☻F*<<²"9☻  xp    sr ←java.lang.StackTraceEl
ementa  ┼Ü&6▌à☻ ♦I
lineNumberL ♫declaringClassq ~ ♠LfileNameq ~ ♠L
methodNameq ~ ♠xp  ♦ìt →java.io.ObjectOutputStreamt ↨ObjectOutputStream.javat ♀w
riteObject0sq ~ ♀  ♣εt →java.io.ObjectOutputStreamt ↨ObjectOutputStream.javat ↕d
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
<set-payload value="#[message.payload[0]['1']]" />
```

That gets the first object in the JSON Array, then the value of the property named `1`.

**EDIT**: Also you got the order of processors in the flow wrong. Since you've put the `set-payload` in a `response` block it will execute **after** the `object-to-json-transformer` which is clearly not what you want.

I suggest you simply go with:

```
...
</db:select>
<set-payload value="#[message.payload[0]['1']]" />
<json:object-to-json-transformer />
```

Comment: I tried #[message.payload[0]['1']] in the SetPayload node.   (the Object-to-JSON did NOT have a return class of java.util.HashMap).

I go the following runtime error

Execution of the expression "message.payload[0]['1']" failed. (org.mule.api.expr
ession.ExpressionRuntimeException). Message payload is of type: String

Comment: This time I tried the SetPayload of #[message.payload[0]['1']]  (the Object-to-JSON DID have a return class of java.util.HashMap this time).
I got the following error:    

The object transformed is of type: "SimpleDataType{type=java.lang.String, mimeTy
pe='*/*'}", but the expected return type is "SimpleDataType{type=java.util.HashM
ap, mimeType='application/json'}". Message payload is of type: LinkedList (org.m
ule.api.transformer.TransformerMessagingException). Message payload is of type:

Comment: Sorry, I can read XML in comments, better edit your question. I've reviewed my answer, because I just realized you were using a `response` block, which is most likely not doing what you wanted it to do.

Comment: I changed the flow.  I hope I did not leave anything out.  However, now I am getting some sort of long list.  How can I resolve this ?  Thanks

Comment: Check my answer: it is `json:object-to-json-transformer` not `json:json-to-object-transformer`.